# postgress - why does CREATE DOMAIN not working?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

The setting:
Node / express / pg

**While the following works fine**

```
CREATE TABLE blah(foo VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY);
```

**The following breaks**

```
CREATE DOMAIN Foo VARCHAR(128);  
CREATE TABLE blah(foo FOO PRIMARY KEY);
```

**With the following error**

```
error: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented  at Parser.parseErrorMessage (.../node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
```

The node code that triggers this is (roughly):

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool();

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

called:

```
await db.query('CREATE DOMAIN Foo VARCHAR(128);');
await db.query('CREATE TABLE blah(foo FOO PRIMARY KEY);');
```

The second call crashes

Comment: That's a node.js error message, not a Postgres error message. Because the SQL code [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=15954550b33fb062a38fd685c2fca280). It seems Node.js can't handle columns defined through a domain.

Comment: This is a client problem. You will have to add the code that generates the error to the question.